# Where are the properties and heists in GTA V online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I was under the impression that GTA V online let you do almost everything in multiplayer that you could do in single player like buy property(most importantly safe-houses).  I'm also really interested in playing in some of the teased co-op heists.

After much server woes, I was able to play a little last night.  I got through the initial street race, did the drug deal, bought some clothes, got a personal vehicle, and played some death matches.  No properties show up on the map yet.  No heists appear available  There's one mission, but that fails out 3 seconds after starting.

Basically I only see PvP content.  I don't even recall any markers for golf or tennis on the mini-map.

I'm only rank 4 or 5 so far.  Is all this content limited to higher ranked players?  Or are there further updates to GTA Online that we have to wait for?

Comment: I am going to guess that one mission will unlock the content you want.  I wasn't able to get past the very first race missions because it simply wouldn't start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.  Part of the problem was that the server situation on day one was preventing texts and calls from Simeon from triggering.

As you level he sends one telling you about purchasing a garage for your car.  This happens at around levels 5-6.  You can find all the properties by going to the in-game website: dynasty8realestate.com.   The properties will also show up on the map if you drive close to them.  They have a symbol that looks like a house; it's also very similar to the convince store icon.

By level 10 it looks like most of the available content has been opened up.

Heist are currently not available, and will arrive in a later update.

Answer (score 2):

The levels bring forward things like property and more unlocks for your character and vehicles. The heists will come at a later update. Which will be in late may 2014.

Answer (score 1):

As CaulynDarr Mentioned, you can go to the website **in-game** at dynasty8realestate.com but here is a list of all of properties online: 
[image]

[image]